# Algorithm to determine whether a given number N can become hypotenuse of right triangle with all 3 integral sides

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, geometry

Suppose you are given hypotenuse of a right angled triangle,then how can you determine whether there are two integral smaller sides possible with the given hypotenuse.

For example, you are given hypotenuse as 5.Then you have to determine whether you have smaller integral sides for the given right triangle.The answer will be `yes` because we can have smaller sides as 3 and 4,hence getting a 3-4-5 right triangle.

Similarly,for hypotenuse as 7 we can have no such right triangle.

**In other words,we have to find whether a given number N can serve as hypotenuse for a right triangle with all 3 sides as integers.**

I went through entire article on [Pythagorean triples](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html) but still no success.I am confused what conditions to check.Please help.

Comment: What is the complexity that you require. IMO this can be modelled as a 2-SUM problem.

Comment: Is the given hypotenuse always an integer?

Comment: Yes all the three sides need to be integers. "In other words,we have to find whether a given number N serve as hypotenuse for a right triangle with all 3 sides as integers."

Answer (score 3):

You have for a *primitive* pythagorean triple:

```
(p^2 - q^2)^2 + (2 * p * q))^2 = (p^2 + q^2)^2 = N^2
```

Suppose p >= q. Then we have

```
N >= 2 * q^2 or q <= sqrt(N / 2)
```

Suppose N = 13. Then we need q <= sqrt(13 / 2) = 2.54

q = 2 => p^2 = 13 - 4 = 9, which is a square.

Hence you can have a small loop of numbers 'i' from 1..sqrt(N/2) and check if N - (i^2) is a square.

This will be **O(sqrt(N))** for a member of a *primitive* pythagorean tuple.

Sample code in C/C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void CheckTuple(int n)
{
    int k = sqrt(n/2.0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        int tmp = sqrt((double)(n - i * i));
        if ((tmp * tmp) == (n - i * i)) {
            printf("%d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2\n", (tmp*tmp - i*i), 2 * tmp * i, n);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%d is not part of a tuple\n", n);
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    CheckTuple(5);
    CheckTuple(6);
    CheckTuple(13);
    CheckTuple(10);
    CheckTuple(25);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2
6 is not part of a tuple
5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2
8^2 + 6^2 = 10^2
7^2 + 24^2 = 25^2
```

Comment: It doesn't always give the right answer. As 51 is a possible hypotenuse but it gives that it isn't.

Comment: @lavee_singh: sorry about the late response. Yes the above finds the _basic / primary_ pythagorean tuples. `51^2 = 24^2 + 45^2` is derived from the basic `17^2 = 8^2 + 15^2` and we will not get the former but will get the latter.

Comment: Ok, now we have to mark all the multiples of already found hypotenuse, in order to prevent such error!

Comment: 5 can be and the other sides are 3 and 4. Non is smaller than or equal to sqrt(5).

Answer (score 2):

```
int hypo = 5, i;
double other = 0;
for (i=1;i<hypo;i++)
{
    other = Math.sqrt(hypo*hypo - i*i);
    if (other == (int)other)
        break;
}

if (i<hypo)
   System.out.println("Yes - (" + (int)other + ", " + i +")" );
else
   System.out.println("No");
```

**O(N)**

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: NO need to perform the following step, because it will always return false.

```
//For each element in the array check whether twice its value equals N^2. If no match occurs then continue to the following.
```

.

```
Have two counters I1 and I2 -> Initialize I1 = 1 and I2 = N-1.
1. Check the sum I1^2 + I2^2;  
2. If the sum is > N^2, decrement the right counter (I2).  
3. If it is < N^2, increment the left counter (I1).

Keep doing the above 3 statements until one of the following happens.    
-> If the sum matches N^2, then a right angled triangle can be formed.
-> If I2 <= I1, then it is not possible to form a triangle.
```

Complexity : O(N)

EDIT: As Dukeling points out, there is no need to store an array. You can directly square I1 and I2 as you go.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to understand this, but it's actually frightfully elegant.  I like it.

Comment: Creating the array is unnecessary (and inefficient). You can just loop over the numbers 1 through N-1 and square them as you go.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been one of my most searched topics on the net. But solution is simple. Coming to the answer let n can be hypotenuse of a right angled triangle. n^2 = a^2 + b^2. (n,a and b are integers). Then obviously for any integer k,  k*n can be hypotenuse. Any prime number of the form (4*l+1) can be hypotenuse (l is an integer). So, split a number into its prime factors. If at least one of the prime factor is in the form 4*l+1 , then obviously the number can be hypotenuse.
Eg : 5 can be expressed as 4*1+1 and 5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2. Similarly, 78 = 2*3*13 and 
13 can be expressed as  4*3+1. and 13^2 = 5^2 + 12^2
=>78^2 = 30^2 + 72^2

Comment: I am wondering that why this answer is not getting much attention. It is brilliant. But it doesn't mention how one may be able to calculate a and b from n.

Comment: Do you know of a way that we can tell how many such triangles exist for a given n? For example for 65 there exist 4 triangles: (16, 63, 65), (25, 60, 65), (33, 56, 65), (39, 52, 65)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

- the "smaller" sides should be smaller, obviously, than the hypotenuse of the triangle.
- we are going to need two more sides.

-> 2 for loops continues to the hypotenuse. something like this one:

```
public static boolean isAnIntegerTriangle(int hypotenuse) {
    for (int i = 0; i < hypotenuse; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hypotenuse; j++) {
            boolean b = ((hypotenuse * hypotenuse) == (i * i + j * j));
            if (b)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAnIntegerTriangle(5));
    System.out.println(isAnIntegerTriangle(10));
    System.out.println(isAnIntegerTriangle(7));
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```