# Nonhypotenuse number

Tags: c, function

A [non-hypotenuse number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonhypotenuse_number.) is a natural number whose square cannot be written as the sum of two non-zero squares.

Given two integers a and b, the task is to find the sum of all odd length non-hypotenuse numbers within the range [L, R], where = and =²−2^.

For example, if a=2 and b=5 then L=2 and R=5²−2²=21.The non-hypotenuse numbers of this range are: 2, 3, 4,  6,  7,  8,  9,  11,12,  14,  16,  18,  19, 21.  But  since  we  only  include  odd length numbers in  our  summation  the  final result is: 39 = 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 +7+ 8 +9.

For the the input 5 25, it returns 65590; however it is supposed to return 72483. It works for the inputs 2 5 and 4 100. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//function, that returns 1 if it is a nonHypoNum
int isNonHypo(int x){
    double temp;
    for (int i=1; i<x; i++){ //iterates through the possible lengths of one leg of the triangle
        temp=sqrt((double)(x*x-i*i)); //calculate third leg
        if (temp==(int)temp) //if the third is a whole number
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//function, that tells weather it has an odd number off digits
int isOddLength(int x){
    int digits=0;
    while (x){
        digits++;
        x/=10;
    }
    return (digits%2==0?0:1);
}

//function, that returns the power of two
int powTwo(int exp){
    int x=2;
    for (;exp>0;exp--){
        x*=2;
    }
    return (x);
}

int main(){
    int a,b,sum=0;

    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for (int Hypo=a; Hypo<=(b*b-powTwo(a)); Hypo++){ //try out numbers in range [a,b²-2^a]
        if (isOddLength(Hypo)&&isNonHypo(Hypo))
            sum+=Hypo;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For "higher numbers" what do you mean? Try to narrow it down. You're using `int`, you might want to consider using `unsigned long long int` instead.

Comment: You area also going to have problems with your results.  You're converting the `double` returned from `sqrt()` directly to an `int` value.  Assuming that fits, that will truncate the result to and `int` value, discarding any fractional part.  And even if you convert `temp` to double, the exact nature of the `==` comparison can fail because floating-point math is not always exact.

Comment: @AndrewHenle His algorithm seems to rely on the truncation

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The `==` is not affected by floating-point rounding because it is comparing two integers computed with integer arithmetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to determine whether a given number N can become hypotenuse of right triangle with all 3 integral sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332978/algorithm-to-determine-whether-a-given-number-n-can-become-hypotenuse-of-right-t)

Comment: How do you know what works and what doesn't? Is there some test case with known answers?

Comment: It seems like each individual part works, but when i put it together, the imputs 5 25 lead to a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some numerical issues with this line in your code

```
temp = sqrt((double)(x*x-i*i));  // where 'temp', 'x' and 'i' are int
```

- Both `x*x` and `i*i` may overflow. It doesn't matter if the result is casted to `double`, because it happens *after* the product are performed. You should use a bigger type, like `long long` and cast the values *before* the multiplications. In that case, the cast to `double` may even introduce some rounding errors.
- Assigning the result of `sqrt` to an `int` may also introduce some unwanted rounding errors. You may use `round()` to prevent those.

In this particular case, you may instead avoid `sqrt` and save some iterations using a different algorithm:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline long long sq(int x)
{
    return (long long)x * x;
}

bool is_nonhypotenuse(int x)
{
    long long square_x = sq(x);

    // Meet in the middle, instead of going up to x
    for (int i = 1, j = x - 1; i <= j; i++)
    {
        long long square_j, target = square_x - sq(i);

        // Iterates, instead of calculating the square root
        while ( (square_j = sq(j)) > target )
            --j;
        if ( square_j == target )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit**

The other problem (probably the most important, given the input data) lies in the function used to calculate the powers of 2.

```
int powTwo(int exp) {
    int x=2;                    // <-- It should start from 1, here
    for (;exp>0;exp--) {
        x*=2;
    }
    return (x);                 // <-- Effectively returns 2^(exp + 1)
}
```

You may consider this more general approach, instead.

```
long long int_pow(int base, int exp)
{
    long long result = 1;
    while ( exp )
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp /= 2;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, given that the base is 2, just use a bit shift

```
int R = b * b - (1 << a);
```

With those modifications, your program should output the desired value. See e.g. [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sND4z6eGlaTxMKB4).

Comment: Thanks Bob! I tried your code, but it gives the same wrong output (see my edited question).